# check_nrpe treats return code 1 as OK

Tags: powershell, return-value, nagios, exit-code, nrpe

I have a powershell script which i call via check_nrpe. When i do passive check i see that the exit code / return value is 1 but it is still treated as state OK instead of CRITICAL.

Basically this script just checks if the target folder **..\bar** is empty. If its empty then script returns '0' which triggers **OK** state in Nagios. If it has files that dont move even after waiting for 25 seconds then it returns '1' which triggers CRITICAL state in Nagios.

I kept few files in folder and can see that the return value is '1'. However nagios still treats it as state **OK**.

Using below command for passive check.

```
$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.XX.X.XXX -c check_kpis -t 30
```

Outout

```
1
```

The script is as below.

```
$path = "D:\foo\bar"
$flagged1 = "D:\temp\flag1.txt"
$flagged2 = "D:\temp\flag2.txt"

$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse
if ( $contents.count -gt 0 )
{
    $contents.Name | Out-File -FilePath $flagged1
    Start-Sleep -s 25
    $contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse
    $contents.Name | Out-File -FilePath $flagged2
    if ( $contents.count -gt 0  )
    {
        $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $flagged1) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $flagged2) -IncludeEqual 
        If ($diff.SideIndicator -eq "==")
        {
            return 1
            exit
        }
        else
        {
            return 0
            exit
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
        exit
    }
}
else
{
    return 0
    exit
}
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It is the EXIT code that determines state, you are using a return which isn't even in a function.  Something like this would be better

```
$path = "D:\foo\bar"
$flagged1 = "D:\temp\flag1.txt"
$flagged2 = "D:\temp\flag2.txt"

$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse
if ( $contents.count -gt 0 )
{
    $contents.Name | Out-File -FilePath $flagged1
    Start-Sleep -s 25
    $contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse
    $contents.Name | Out-File -FilePath $flagged2
    if ( $contents.count -gt 0  )
    {
        $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $flagged1) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $flagged2) -IncludeEqual 
        If ($diff.SideIndicator -eq "==")
        {
            echo 1
            exit 1
        }
        else
        {
            echo 0
            exit 0
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0
        exit 0
    }
}
else
{
    echo 0
    exit 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your powershell command in Nsclint.ini file you must define your script like:

```
check_esomething=cmd /c echo scripts\check_something.ps1; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -
```

So you must add "exit($lastexitcode)" statement in your definition.

Enjoy!